# Holding on to a bar (a horizontal pull up one obviously) thicker

Tags: pull-ups, grip-strength, grip

There is a challenge at a beach I go to. Pay 2.5 euros for the opportunity to try and hold on to a bar for longer than 2 minutes. The bar is not fixed, meaning it can rotate. On a fixed bar I can hold on for a minute that isnt too thick. How much does this non fixed component act on your result? If I were to hold the bar with a pronated grip with thumbs over the bar , I would think that it is the same thing. Thoughts on this? Does anyone now the record for longest time holding on to a bar?

Comment: Rotate how? Are you able to grab with a hand on either side (much like you would a pole vault pole)?

Comment: Nope, only holding it traditionally like doing a normal pullup is allowed.

Comment: Or a chinup, that grip is for example

Comment: By rotate i mean like if you were to try to rotate a fixed bar in the motion of ramping up a motorcycle while  holding the bar, it would be easy to do with this unfixed bar.

Comment: Is there any sort of lofty prize for holding onto the bar for more than 2 minutes?

Comment: The fact that it rotates won't make very much difference. With a pronated grip you should be pretty balanced normally and if not you'll rotate a few degrees in order to be balanced.

Answer (score 2):

Overhand grip will focus on your forarms more than a underhand grip. Most people will be better at a overhand grip. Ref: http://www.umich.edu/~mvs330/f00/domination/main.html

Optimal position for your hands on the bar depends entirely on how your body is built. Someone with strong arms can do a vertical hang (narrow grip) easily and someone with strong back will excel at a wide grip hold.

Optimal would be a over and under grip (same as a deadlift) at slightly wider than shoulder width.